# A Game of Thrones Feast breaking ties for objectives

Tags: game-of-thrones

In A Game of Thrones the board game the player who holds the iron throne breaks ties. In the expansion A Feast for Crows, objective cards are introduced such as

> Control more land areas than any other house

If two players are tied for most number of land areas, is a player able to score this objective? If so does the iron throne player decide who has the "most" land areas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rulebook](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/agot-bg-2nd-ed/support/VA65_AGoT2_Rulebook_web.pdf), p.8 (emphasis added):

> The outcome of all ties **in bidding** is decided by the player holding the Iron Throne token. This player places the Influence tokens of tied players on the highest (i.e., left-most) available positions on the track, in the order of his choice.

Rulebook, p.11:

> **The Iron Throne Token**
>
> The player holding this token decides the outcome of all ties that occur in
> the game, with the exception of ties in combat (which are resolved by a player’s
> position on the Fiefdoms track) and ties in determining the winner of the game.

Of course there is no reference to the FFC objective cards in the rulebook for the base game (since the expansion came afterwards), but I think a strict reading of the objective card itself (control **more** *X* than any other House) combined with the normal use of the Iron Throne token in the base game (breaks all ties in *bidding*, but not in combat or determining the winner of the game) means that if two players are tied for the most *X*, the player holding the objective for having the most *X* cannot score it.

Edit: The only reference to scoring in the FFC rules that seems relevant is on pp.7-8:

> In turn order, each player may choose to score **one** Objective card of his choice from his Objective hand (if the criterion described is fulfilled) ...

In my opinion, this doesn't shed any further light on the issue, but I included it for completeness.

Comment: This is what we figured, but we were a bit confused based on the two wordings of the original use of the iron throne. In the future we'll use it only to break "bidding" ties.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot score this objective.

If two players control the same amount of land, it is quite clear that you **do not** control more land than any other players, and hence you cannot score the objective as the criterion described has **not** been fulfilled.

The second part of your question, regarding the Iron Throne, is not relevant. From memory, all the objectives had a hard criteria that could not be 'shared' between players (e.g. controlling particular locations etc)